# AJAX SOAP request - Safari changing POST to OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, soap, safari

I'm trying to send a SOAP action from a js running on my local machine to another device on my network. I notice that Firefox is successful, but Safari changes the header to say OPTIONS instead of POST. Any ideas?